# Editing the Content of Password Protected Posts using ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I wanted to change My "Password Protected" post's default subject line to be changed and enter different content for each posts. That's why I installed ACF and created a "Wysiwyg Editor" where I can add my custom content.

Now, on my functions.php file, I added the following code:

```
<?php
add_filter( 'the_password_form', 'custom_password_form' );
function custom_password_form() {
    global $post;
    $label = 'pwbox-'.( empty( $post->ID ) ? rand() : $post->ID );
    $o = '<form class="protected-post-form" action="' . get_option('siteurl') . '/wp-pass.php" method="post">
    ' . __( "<?php the_field('password_protected_post_special_content'); ?>" ) . '
    <label class="pass-label" for="' . $label . '">' . __( "Enter Your Password Here:" ) . ' </label><input name="post_password" id="' . $label . '" type="password" style="background: #ffffff; border:1px solid #999; color:#333333; padding:10px;margin:15px auto;" size="20" /><input type="submit" name="Submit" class="button" value="' . esc_attr__( "Submit" ) . '" />
    </form>
    ';
    return $o;
}
?>
```

As u see, I put this field `<?php the_field('password_protected_post_special_content'); ?>` to show the editor contents on the post. But, it is not showing up on the post. Here is a screenshot:

http://prntscr.com/einiq9

Did I do anything wrong?